# How do i upgrade a user license for devops access level for "Basic + Test Plan"?

Tags: azure-devops

I have 2 staff members that have been invited to another organisations devops site. i.e. https://dev.azure.com/othercompany
The administrator wants to give them an access level of "Basic + Test Plan".

They have told the 2 staff that they need to be given licenses for "Basic + Test Plan" in their own Azure AD portal.

I cannot see where to do this? Any ideas? see screenshot below..

Thanks for your time,

Ollie
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2B78.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Basic + Test Plan access level is managed at azure devops organisation Billing page.

The administrator should **set up billing** to associate to a valid Azure subscription in Billing page of Organization settings.[image]

After setting up the billing. The administrator can go to **Users** page under **Organization settings** and click on the **3dots** beside the user and choose c**hange access level** to assign the user Basic+Test Plans access level. 
[image]

For more information check document [Manage paid access for users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/buy-basic-access-add-users?view=azure-devops) on Microsoft site.